# Start wpf with code that's not a window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In Winforms you just have the Main function and that's what runs first, but in WPF you set the window you want to start with in the Application.xaml file. If I try to run anything other than a window, how would I do that? I'm porting over a winforms application that does some logic at start to determine which window to open and I'd rather have it just be a class that runs than a window that never appears.

Comment: Write it in c# you'd be able to do that - not sure in VB - c# has a Program.cs file which contains the entry point that you can modify, must be something similar in VB - let me see

Comment: doesn't the App.Startup event meets your needS?

Comment: @SteveB I don't know, I didn't try it. I don't know about every event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the [`StartupUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) from `App.xaml`, override [`OnStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx) in `App.xaml.cs`.